# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 no se reconoce en la maquina local

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

EL problema es que al momento de cargar el archivo xlsx, me sale el error de "El proveedor "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" no está registrado en el equipo local"; aunque si tengo instalado este componente en la maquina.
Ademas he cambiado la opcion de "any cpu" a "x86"  y el problema persiste.

saben de alguna otra opcion? o como cargar el "xlsx" de otra manera a un gridview. a continuacion el codigo:

```
protected void Benvarch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = "";
            if (fuarchivo.HasFile) {

                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fuarchivo.PostedFile.FileName);
                string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fuarchivo.PostedFile.FileName);
                string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + fileName);
                fuarchivo.SaveAs(fileLocation);
                //Check whether file extension is xls or xslx
                if (fileExtension == ".xls")
                {

                    connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";





                }
                else if (fileExtension == ".xlsx") {

                    connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";

                }

                //Create OleDB Connection and OleDb Command
                OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dtExcelRecords = new DataTable();
                con.Open();
                DataTable dtExcelSheetName = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                string getExcelSheetName = dtExcelSheetName.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + "]";
                dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                dAdapter.Fill(dtExcelRecords);
                con.Close();
                gvcarga.DataSource = dtExcelRecords;
                gvcarga.DataBind();


            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando tienes ese error es porque debes instalar el redistribuible de `ACE.OLEDB.12`

Lo descargas de aqui

[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

aqui se menciona mas sobre el problema

[Installing the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 Provider for Both 64-bit and 32-bit Processing](https://datasavvy.me/2017/07/20/installing-the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-for-both-64-bit-and-32-bit-processing/)

Si quieres una alternativa para trabajar el `excel` podrias usar una libreria basada en `open xml` como ser `ClosedXML`

[ClosedXML nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML/)

algo como esto

```
using (XLWorkbook workBook = new XLWorkbook(filePath))
{
    //Read the first Sheet from Excel file.
    IXLWorksheet workSheet = workBook.Worksheet(1);
```

para acceder al `worksheet`

[Read and import Excel file data to DataGridView using ClosedXml using C# and VB.Net](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Read-and-import-Excel-file-data-to-DataGridView-using-ClosedXml-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

Comment: el redistributibe esta instalado, pero no lo reconoce :( ... sin embargo voy a mirar la otra opcion que me diste..

Comment: que este instalado y no lo reconozca es algo raro, despues de instalarlo reniciaste la pc ? a veces eso afecta en este tipo de componentes